# Website is not responsive on actual cell phones, but responsive when viewed in inspector tools

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

This website...

http://www.collegefundingremedies.com

is responsive on my computer, and displays correctly when I Inspect Elements through Google Chrome and click on the mobile the different mobile views, but when I open the website on an actual mobile phone, everything is unaligned and badly formatted. What am I missing here?

I have the...

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the index and media queries set up, so I'm not sure what's going on at all. Please help.

Comment: It IS actually responsive. But one of the elements on the page seems to be "flowing out" of the viewport, causing a slight horizontal scroll.

Comment: @edwardm do you have an idea of how I can find it. I'm inspecting it with Chrome developer tools but can't seem to find it that way. Please help :/

Comment: @edwardm also, how were you able to find that.